# Cant run yacc nor flex commands VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, bison, yacc, lex

I've installed Lex Flex Yacc Bison extension in Visual Studio Code, created a sample project, navigated to folder in the terminal, but when I run `yacc -d syntax.y`, the terminal doesn't recognize the `yacc` command. line 1 begins with `%{`. The only command that seems to work is `ls` to list the files in the current directory.

```
yacc : The term 'yacc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ yacc -d syntax.y
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Yacc:String) [], 
      CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Lex Flex Yacc Bison](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=faustinoaq.lex-flex-yacc-bison) extension only provides syntax highlighting for the input files to these tools; it does not include the tools themselves.

On Windows, probably the easiest way to get them is to install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).  Cygwin has `flex`, `yacc`, and `bison`.  Cygwin does not have a port of `lex`.  I recommend using `flex` for lexical analysis and `bison` for grammatical analysis, since those are the actively mantained successors of `lex` and `yacc`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows you can install devc++ app due to my knowledge it has support for yacc and lex files it creates files automatically without much effort but I don't know any other app's that extension in visual studio code is for syntax highlighting only.